# Attempting to assign mail merge to open excel file

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, mailmerge

```
Sub MyTemplate()

    Dim wordApp As Word.Application
    Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
    Dim wordMailMerge As Word.MailMerge
    Dim wordPath As String
    Dim excelPath As String
       
    CurrentWorksheet = ActiveSheet.Name
    excelPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Sticker Maker.xlsm"

                
                wordPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Inventory Labels.docx"
                Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
                Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(wordPath)
                Set wordMailMerge = wordDoc.MailMerge
                
                wordMailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:=excelPath, SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `'Barcode$'`"
                wordMailMerge.Execute
                'wordDoc.Close
                wordApp.Visible = True

    Set wordMailMerge = Nothing
    Set wordDoc = Nothing
    Set wordApp = Nothing
    Sheets(CurrentWorksheet).Select

End Sub
```

The portion of this code that opens the excel file
wordMailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:=excelPath, SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `'Barcode$'`"
throws an error because the file is already open. (that file is where the code is running) I just need it to assign the data from the workbook without opening it. because it will already be open running the macro.

Comment: See *Run a Mailmerge from Excel, Sending the Output to Individual Files* in the **Mailmerge Tips & Tricks** thread at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html

Answer (score 0):

Add the read only property when opening the file:

```
wordMailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:=excelPath, ReadOnly:=True, SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `'Barcode$'`"
```

Comment: there is no way to reference the active document? Yes that solves the issue, but it's opening a record that is going to grow over time. opening a second copy now won't present an issue but who knows if they are still using this 5 years from now on the same computer it may crash every time.

Comment: actually this didn't fix the problem. it still says I need permission from the person who has the file open to even view it as read only.

Comment: You can use ActiveWorkook.Name instead of the path to reference the Excel file you're in. Read only should work.